# tvOS tableView scroll smooth from cell to cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, tvos, tvos9.1

In my tvOS-app I use a tableView with custom cells. If the cell is higher than the TV-screen it will show the "center-part" of the cell (top and bottom are not visible) and scrolling up or down will center the cell above or below. Is it possible and if, how, to change the "jumping" from cell to cell to a smooth scrolling like in iOS?

Comment: You should show focus. you should be resizing the images so they fit sensibly on screen...

Comment: I don't have an image inside. The cell contains reviews and some customer writes 1 line, others half a book. In the second case there is only the middle part of text visible because the cell is 1500px heigh what results that on top and bottom about 250px are cut off :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should limit your cells to use a fixed height for a few lines of text and show focus. When a user selects one of the cells you can then expand / zoom / transition to show the whole text is a specific scrollable text view. This interface maintains the users understanding of content, lists and block text.

Comment: Maybe a (the?) solution - but for my "feeling" not very user friendly. If I went through reviews and have to click to view the entire content it gets annoying. It will be ok if using a keyboard with only up/down arrows as in the 80s. With a remote to slide smoothly and continuous up and down it seems to me like a relict from last millennium. If Apple insists on that way I would say we are going backwards in big steps!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. Knowing what to search could be an advantage ;-)

Adding this simple line gives me the handling like in iOS:

```
self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[@(UITouchTypeIndirect)];
```

Comment: I am facing a similar problem I have one cell which has lot of text content and does not show up entirely and upon scrolling down it directly shifts its focus to second cell. I used your code and for the cell which has large text it works properly but the cells that are there after that, the scroll direction works in opposite direction. Are there any other properties you had set along with this